# Discrete and continuous legend ono same plot for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am making a plot which shows three different types. 
One of the types has a continuous number of variances so it is shown using a continuous colour scale.
The other two types have their own colours.

I can only get a legend to show for the continuous type, not the two discrete types.  I tried using the advice [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-2/), but got the message

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill

How can I get a legend for both the continuous and discrete lines?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

type1 <- tibble(y = rep(1:10, each = 20 ), x =  rep(1:20, times = 10), type = rep(1:10, each = 20 ) %>% as.character)

type2 <- tibble(y = seq(from = 0.5, to = 10, by=0.5), x = 1:20, type = "A")
type3 <- tibble(y = seq(from = 10, to = 0.5, by=-0.5), x = 1:20, type = "B")

 type1 %>% #need to remove infinte values 
    ggplot(aes(x, y, group = type)) + 
   geom_line(aes(colour = y)) +  
   scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("red",   "limegreen"), name = "Type1 value") +
   geom_line(data = type2, 
             aes(x,y)) +
   geom_line(data = type3, 
             aes(x, y), colour = "blue" )
```

The plot produced looks like this.
I want the same plot but with an additional legend that shows a black for type 2 and blue for type 3. Thus the legend would be a mix of discrete and continuous.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so a whole new answer:

here it is:

```
type1 %>% #need to remove infinte values 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group = type)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = y), show.legend = TRUE) +  
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("red",   "limegreen"), name = "Type1 value") +
  geom_line(data = type2, 
        aes(x,y, fill = 'type2'), color = 'black') +
  geom_line(data = type3, 
        aes(x, y, fill = 'type3'), color = 'blue') +
  scale_fill_manual("Types", values=c(1, 1),
        guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("black", "blue")))
  )
```

[image]

It's a bit of an annoying workaround, but it does the job

You basically use `show.legend` to get the first legend, and the `fill` to force the second legend (so ignore the warning, because obviously there is nothing to fill in a line), and then `guide_legend` lets you add the colors to the legend

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what is the desired output is

for example like this:

```
type1 %>% #need to remove infinte values 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group = type)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = 'type1')) +
  geom_line(data = type2, aes(x,y, color='type2'))  +
  geom_line(data = type3, aes(x, y, color='type3'))
```

[image]

or

```
 type1 %>% #need to remove infinte values 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group = type)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = type), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(data = type2, aes(x,y, color='type2'), show.legend = TRUE)  +
  geom_line(data = type3, aes(x, y, color='type3'), show.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

or is it something entirely different

Comment: Thanks. These plots simply use discrete colouring. They can be made just by binding the data frames together and making a simple line plot. I want to keep the continuous colour legend and in addition, have the type 2 and 3 represented as discrete colours. I have made an edite to my question just above the plot.

Comment: aha, got it! take a look at my new answer